# delete photos in my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, photolibrary

I understand that I can't programmatically delete photos from my app . Because Apple writes that we can only add photos

> To save a still image to the user’s Saved Photos album, use the
>   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function. To save a movie to the
>   user’s Saved Photos album,  use the
>   UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum function.

But I find project that have photos in project, so I can delete photos from this app by clicking delete icon (but still it crashes then =) ) [project](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone)

And now I see only two ways:

1. Save photos in my project folder and then I can do with it what I want. Can I do it? I think no =(
2. Open standart Photos app from my app (open with...) but I read some threads about it, and I understood that it's impossible. That's right?
3. Update! I written this point below. Can I create links in my app to photos in Photo Library? And then, if I want to delete photo from my app, I will delete link, so i will not see photo in my app, but it still stay in Photo Library. Does it possible?

So after all my searching I haven't found a solution. Are their some ways to solve my problem?

Comment: Does "unimpossible" actually mean "possible"?

Comment: No it is mean impossible, thank you for editing, sometimes i make mistakes with English, sorry

Comment: It's all good, we all make mistakes and that's why we can edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Youtube I find [next video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TP5NghkLY0M) and I understand that I can save photo to document directory. It was next code in video

```
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation (image);
NSString *myGrabbedImage = @"myGrabbedImage.png";
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomainns (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:myGrabbedImage];
[data writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
```

So I understand that is simple to save photo from Photo Library to my array, and then open photos from array. And I will can than simply delete photos by remove them from my array. Ok, but now I have 2 questions:

> 1. How I can distinguish photos that i will save in my array? If I will allocate same photo in Photo Library it will be save some times - it's not good.
> 2. So it will be work only with PNG images?

PS Sorry, if this questions very newbiest, but my brain exploded after allday searching.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to take a photo of the camera and get a `UIImage` and write it to a folder that your app owns. You can't write it to your apps space because you only have read access to it. The folder of choice for your problem would be the Documents folder. Have a look [here](http://www.wmdeveloper.com/2010/09/save-and-load-uiimage-in-documents.html?m=1).

Comment: oh, and can I create NSArray with links on photos in Photo Library? And then, if I will want to delete photo - link to photo will be delete and i will not see this photo in my app, but this photo still stay in photo library? If it's possible, maybe you can give me link to such project? thanks